# Библиотека python для работы с ssas

Tags: python, python-3.x, olap, ssas

Подскажите, какая есть удобная библиотека для работы питоном с ssas. 
Интересует возможность процессить куб, вытаскивать из куба данные

Answer (score 1):

Есть библиотека [olap.xmla на PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/xmla/), вот достаточно [подробный пример](http://blog.soft-prestidigitation.com/ssas-via-python.html) её применения.

Помимо этого есть вариант использования [IronPython](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronPython) и соответствующих DLL, небольшой пример можно [посмотреть здесь](https://gist.github.com/dankor/bd8b944820a902e3f90a12231cb95a64).